# Kohana autoload not working

Tags: php, kohana

I'm attempting to get a working installation of this (https://github.com/bertelsmannstift/Beteiligungskompass) project running.

It seems to me that the autoloading is not working properly because I'm getting the below error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Helper_Mobile' not found in
/srv/www/releases/20131205104015/application/classes/controller/base.php
on line 63" while reading upstream, client: 92.239.225.104, 
server: *****, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:",
```

The autoloading IS working though. This line in `bootstrap.php`

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```

Is present and removing it breaks things much earlier. So why can't Kohana find the class in `/srv/www/releases/20131205104015/application/classes/helper/mobile.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you use Kohana 3.3 for an application that for written for 3.2 or maybe 3.1.

Try an other version or read the [migrating guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions).

`mobile/helper.php` uses short open tags. Have you tried setting short_open_tags to true in your `php.ini`?

Comment: I don't THINK this is the case, mainly because `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'helper_mobile' not found in /srv/www/releases/20131205104015/application/classes/controller/base.php on line 63` also fails. And the checked out version of Kohana in the system folder is 3.2 (commit 44fcb1b68a760f4d9ab46607776671b2d40d3647)

Comment: Ah, the mobile_helper.php seems to use the short tag `<?` while controller/base.php uses `<?php`. Did you check that?

Comment: Genius! Getting past that error now at least :) I must be running this under a stricter version of PHP than the original people? I'll investigate that, edit your answer and give you the tick in a minute